# How to create custom pages in .Net Maui?

Tags: c#, maui

I have a custom page template defined as follows :

**Page1 :**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
                 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                 x:Class="MyApp.Resources.Controls.Page1"             
                 Title="Page1">
        
        <ContentPage.ControlTemplate>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Grid RowDefinitions="auto,*">
                    <Label Text="Label 1" Grid.Row="0">

                    <!-- Content of page 1 -->
                    <ContentPresenter Grid.Row="1" />                
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </ContentPage.ControlTemplate>
    </ContentPage>
```

All the pages inheriting from Page1, have **"Label 1"**. So this is working fine.

Now I need to create a new custom page inherting from **Page1**. Basically adding new elements to the template and keep what is already in Page1.

**Page2 :**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <Controls:Page1 xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
                 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                 x:Class="MyApp.Resources.Controls.Page2"     
                 xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:MyApp.Resources.Controls"               
                 Title="Page2">

        <Controls:Page1.ControlTemplate>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Grid RowDefinitions="auto,*" >   
                    <Label Text="Label 2" Grid.Row="0">
                    
                    <!-- Content of page 2 -->
                    <ContentPresenter Grid.Row="1"/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
            
        </Controls:Page1.ControlTemplate>
    </Controls:Page1>
```

Now the pages inheriting from **Page2** don't have **"Label 1"**. They have only "Label 2". While I'm expecting these pages to have both **"Label 1"** and **"Label 2"**.

How can I solve that?

Comment: That's not how XAML in general works, instead of page inheritance like this it favors templating and composition.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Blindy . Any link where can I find more about this please ?

Comment: [Substitute content into a contentpresenter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/templates/control-template#substitute-content-into-a-contentpresenter). Have ONE control template, in a separate file, that is used by BOTH pages. In each page, you substitute the content of the content presenter.

Comment: I tested the code you provided. If you remove `ControlTemplate` label of Page2, "Label 1" will appear. That's because `ControlTemplate` label of Page2 covers `ControlTemplate` label of Page1.

Answer (score 0):

Short version of what you can do:

1. Make custom control class (lets say in namespace Controls), inheriting ContentView

   public class MyControl : ContentView
2. In ResourceDictionary, add control template, and inside it, add your VisualElements.

   < ControlTemplate x:Key="MyControlTemplate" >
   ...
   < /ControlTemplate >
3. In your View, add your control:

   < controls:MyControl ControlTemplate="{StaticResource MyControlTemplate}" />

Where controls is:

```
xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:MyNamespace.Controls"
```

And now your user interface can be reused in every page you want.
(And bind commands/properties to it, use different templates, etc...)

Best part is that you make changes at one place, and it is changed across your whole project.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution works fine. Modify page2 as a standard page and inherit as said page1.
Now Page2 will show both labels Label 1 and Label 2.

```
<Controls:Page1 x:Class="MyApp.Resources.Controls.Page2" 
                Title="Page2">

    <Grid RowDefinitions="auto,*" >   
        <Label Text="Label 2" Grid.Row="0">
             
        <!-- more xaml here -->       
    </Grid>
</Controls:Page1>
```